# List of Android native servers

Tags: android, android-source

How to get a full list of the Android native servers. To be specific I ask about Android 7.1.2. I try a several approaches but in my opinion both of them are wrong.

First:

```
AOSP$ ls -l out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system/bin/ | grep server
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gluttton gluttton   13840 сер  7 00:37 audioserver
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gluttton gluttton    5560 сер  7 00:40 cameraserver
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gluttton gluttton  124432 сер  7 01:00 drmserver
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gluttton gluttton 1125788 сер  7 01:00 gdbserver
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gluttton gluttton 1115512 сер  7 01:00 gdbserver64
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gluttton gluttton   17936 сер  7 01:05 mediadrmserver
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gluttton gluttton    9652 сер  7 01:05 mediaserver
```

But not all servers are called `<some>server` and `surfaceflinger` is a example of such exception.

Second:

```
AOSP$ grep native frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java
    private static native void startSensorService();
            // libnativehelper's JniInvocation::Init code where we already
           // Initialize native services.
                    reportWtf("observing native crashes", e);
```

But it looks like not all servers are started by the `SystemServer`.

Bonus question: is there difference between `native server` and `native service`?

Comment: Looks like related: http://android-developers.narkive.com/coXimivq/native-daemons-started-by-init .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. native server is c/c++ program (with void main(argc, argv){} entry point) that is completely independent from android java code (ie. zygote). So you can start android with just initd and without zygote or system server. And run those native servers from init.rc of your board.

So when you look for list of all of them, read /init.rc from your running device. And look for 'service ...' sections. You will have few init*.rc files.
Some are from system/core/rootdir/init*rc and some are from
device/name_of_the_manufacturer/name_of_board/init*rc

Each section 'system ...' defines what to start by initd after kernel booted.

service audioserver /system/bin/audioserver

```
class main

user audioserver

# media gid needed for /dev/fm (radio) and for /data/misc/media (tee)

group audio camera drmrpc inet media mediadrm net_bt net_bt_admin net_bw_acct

ioprio rt 4

writepid /dev/cpuset/foreground/tasks /dev/stune/foreground/tasks
```

In android 7 you have to find -name init*.rc because they are scattered all aver the source tree.

So to answer your question :
grep -rn service --include=*init*rc

in your root dir of your source tree and ignore those from different device/manufacturers/

Answer (score 2):

By 'native' people mean 'written in native platforms language' this means C/C++ for android. A service usually means 'object in memory that has exposed binder interface'. Where other processes can call it's IBinder derived interface. So in example that audioserver from ps list it's a server started by init.rc on boot, it's written in C++ you can call it a native server. It has at least 2 services inside: audio_flinger and audio_policy - they are also C/C++ code, they are objects that expose it's IBinder interface so you can call them 'native services'.

a list of all services is here:
adb shell service list

some inside runtime info if you like to runtime debug:

adb shell dumpsys

A list of servers/deamons you do it correctly - 'ps' but not all of them like 'rild' or mentioned 'surfaceflinger' has a server in its name.

Read your /system/core/rootdir/init.rc plus device///init*.rc in your android source directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Most of your suggestions I have done but it did not help me. When I talk about `native` service I mean that it do not need `zygote` or `system_server` to be launched - is it correct?

Comment: Yes, native server is c/c++ program (with void main(argc, argv){} entry point) that is completely independent from android java code (ie. zygote). So you can start android with just initd and without zygote or system server. And run those native servers from init.rc of your board.

So when you look for list of all of them, read /init.rc from your running device. And look for